# Where to call invalidateOptionsMenu() while using ViewPagers

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I am using a `ViewPager` along with a `FragmentPagerAdapter` to swipe through tabs and I want each fragment to display a different Options Menu.

I have the code in the `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` method for each fragment but this method never seems to be called by the `ViewPager` when swiping through the fragments so the options menu in the action bar never changes.

Where do I call the `invalidateOptionsMenu()` method in order to make it so each fragment has its own unique Options Menu in the Action Bar?

Comment: I am not sure but try experimenting `setOnPageChangeListener` it is the callback for tab switching.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show menu items depending ViewPager Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28342181/show-menu-items-depending-viewpager-android)